# Project in JSP need Suggestions

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, jakarta-ee

I am new to Java. But I studies Core Java and J2EE1.4(Servlet N JSP) And recently I got one project in Java. This project is basically used for generating reports.

I am planning to use Hibernate for Database Operations with Struts. Any suggestions to use another framework in place of Sturts like Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following technologies for the project

Presentation Layer: Spring MVC web Flow.
Data Access Layer: Hibernate.
Report Generation: Spring Reporting Templates.

I suggest to Integrate Spring with Hibernate. Because 
Hibernate is good for handling the Data Base operations. 
Spring MVC 3.1 is having the more futures than Struts 1.3/2.0. 
Spring provided DataSource/ Entity Manager more efficiently for the Hibernate.
Spring having String Templates to generate the Reports in your required format

Comment: Thanks Pavan Kumar. I am also thinking to implement Spring for this project. Can you tell me the any good links to start Spring as a beginner.